# Images of homotopic paths are homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a space and $f,g:I\to X$ be two paths that are homotopic to each other. Denote $\tilde{f}$ and $\tilde{g}$ to be the images of $f,g$ in $X$. Is it true that $\tilde{f}$ is homeomorphic to $\tilde{g}$ under their subspace topologies induced from $X$? Intuition suggests so, but I'm not sure of how to prove this. Thanks!

Comment: What if one path going from the origin to $(1,0)$ makes a loop (i.e.has a self-intersection) and the other path just goes directly along the $x$-axis? My understanding of homotopy ( ancient ! ) says the two paths are homotopic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not true. For instance, let $X = \mathbb R$. Consider $f,g:I\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ via $f(x)=x$ ang $g(x)=0$. Then $f$ and $g$ are homotopic via $H(x,t)= tx$. However, the image of $g$ is a single point while the image of $f$ is $[0,1]$. These are certainly not homeomorphic.